# Magento 2: Pre-load key request fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2

Tags: magento2, pagespeed

How can I remove fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2 from google page speed insight. From which less file this font is being loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can answer to this question? Which core file do we need to override?

Comment: did you get any solution about this? as i am getting same error in my one project

Answer (score 0):

```
<remove src="fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2"/>
<remove src="fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff2"/>
<remove src="fonts/opensans/semibold/opensans-600.woff2"/>
<remove src="fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff2"/>
<remove src="fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2"/>
```

Solved it using the above remove src tag in default_head_blocks.xml .